Which part of the Java Language Specification specifies the behavior of this conversion?
I was working on a project that parses Java code. While testing my project on some code I found out that it throws an error on cases like the one under, specifically on the conversion of type B<A<? extends S>> in main to B<A<? extends T>> in f. I want to know exactly how the Java compiler handles this, which is probably specified somewhere in the Java Language Standard, but I can't find the specifications. It will be very helpful if someone happened to know where this is specified so I can make my project able to handle this behavior.
public class Main {
    public interface A<T> {}
    public static class B<T> {}
    private static <T> void f(B<A<? extends T>> ignored) {}
    public static <S> void main(String[] args) {
        f(new B<A<? extends S>>());
    }
}

I scanned through the sections related to Wildcards and Generic types in JLS but I failed to find any specifications on this case.

Is the problem in the conversion? I'm pretty sure you can't have a generic main. I can't look up the JLS right now, but try looking in the section that defines main.

The problem will be that the compiler can't infer that B<A<? extends T>> and B<A<? extends S>> are equivalent for some binding of S and T.  The relevant rules are probably in Chapter 19.  (Beware: type inference is not an easy topic.)

(I guess you are aware that there are three distinct T types in your example ...)

@StephenC I threw OP's code into ideone, and if you change main's name so it's not a main, it compiles: https://ideone.com/S9dbov

Ah ... OK.  So I guess the "conversion" is valid.  But the explanation of what is valid and what isn't will be in ... or will include ... Chapter 19.  That's what the OP needs to understand if he is going to implement this aspect of Java.

But I would also note that public static <S> void main(String[] args) should parse ... and indeed, compile without errors.  (It does with javac too!). The problem is that the main method would not be recognized as an entry point method ... because of the <S>.  Hence you wouldn't be able to run it ... by itself.

Hm, interesting that ideone won't let it compile with <S>. The only thing I can find in the JLS is section 12.1.4, which specifies that the method must be public static void and take a String[] (or String...). It doesn't say it can't have any generic parameters.

Oh, check that -- it looks like it does compile, but indeed can't find main. I must have misread the error message earlier.

I also just realized I may have misread OP's question.I thought they were saying that javac treats their code as an error, but their compiler allows it; but they're saying the opposite. So two things: (1) I agree, it's somewhere in the type inference section (which I think is 18, not 19? link), which is not easy; and (2) I think it's clearly time for me to get to bed. :-)

How is that code being executed? What exactly do you mean by "throws an error"? If it is an Exception/Error, please include the error message and relevant stack trace in the question, best with a [mre]  (( posted code works without Exception in Eclipse or OpenJDK 23 ))

The reason I use <S> main is because this is the minimal reproducible example that I found that makes my parser throw an error. I know that main with <S> probably leads to undefined behavior, but it does compile with javac. Also thanks everyone for the help! I will try to find the specification in JLS Chapter 18.

@StephenC JDK23 is quite happy with compile + run class with public static <S> void main(String[] args)
